How do I [using selenium webdriver] target ANY span containing specific information?
Currently, I'm working on coding a webscraper of sorts; I want to change pages and still be able to detect what I'm looking for in terms of certain qualities.
Right now I'm using:
mouse_tracker = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[span[contains(text(), 'PDF')]]")

But it's unable to select any but the first of the links that fit the qualities. What I'm looking for is being able to select any link that has those qualities (but only one at a time). For example, if I switch pages or scroll down a page to get a deeper amount of results, it'll be able to select one of those links with the same qualities instead of being fixated on the first link it sees.

find_elements will return an array of webelement references.  (For some sites you'll need some sleep before using it as JS may be populating the DOM... alternatively you can catch stale element exceptions and re-get the array if caught.)  While iterating a webelement reference array you should avoid doing any operations which might cause a DOM update.   This will cause your references to go stale.

Find elements as browsenator said:
mouse_tracker = browser.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[span[contains(text(), 'PDF')]]")

